# How to use a custom downloads folder and the launcher executable path?

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I want to download Chromium under a specific path. But to be able to then launch Chromium using an executable under that same path, I have to construct an executable path and that seems a little clumsy. I'm hoping there's a better way I'm currently missing. Here's the relevant version of my code basically:

```
string chromiumDownloadsPath =
    String.Format(
        @"{0}\Puppeteer Sharp downloads",
        baseDirectoryPath
        );

Downloader downloader = new Downloader(chromiumDownloadsPath);
await downloader.DownloadRevisionAsync(chromiumRevision);

var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(
    new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true,
        ExecutablePath =
            String.Format(
                @"{0}\Win32-{1}\chrome-win32\chrome.exe",
                chromiumDownloadsPath,
                chromiumRevision
                )
    },
    chromiumRevision
    );
```

What seems clumsy in particular is needing to add the `"\Win32-{1}\chrome-win32"` portion of the path. I was expecting `Puppeteer.LaunchAsync` to 'know' how to find an executable given a revision number because it 'should' already 'know' that I've directed Puppeteer Sharp to download the Chromium builds to a custom directory and I would think it has enough info to determine the platform too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Downloader` class contains a method `public string GetExecutablePath(int revision)` that does exactly what I was expecting to be possible. The `ExecutablePath` property of the `LaunchOptions` object should thus be just:

```
        ExecutablePath = downloader.GetExecutablePath(chromiumRevision)
```

Comment: With the newer versions it seems you can access this information like: `browserFetcherInstance.ExecutablePath`